# Composition of Euler angles

Tags: rotations

I have a problem in which I apply a sequence of $N$ rotations, each one of different angles $\theta_1,...,\theta_N$. But my angle here are associated to rotations around either $x$ or $y$ axis in the following form:

$R=R_y(\theta_N)R_x(\theta_{N-1})...R_x(\theta_2)R_y(\theta_1)$. In a way it is a composition of rotations specified by Euler angle around the system of axis $yxy$.

My question is the following:

From what I read, composition of $N$ rotations around arbitrary axes is a very complicated problem to obtain "nice" analytic formulas. However, here I use as "basis" of rotations $x$ and $y$ axis. In this particular case, are there some method to know what would be the Euler angle around those same axes $xyx$ (having "nice" analytical formulas) ?

Said differently, given two rotations specified by their Euler angles, is there a nice formula to have the Euler angles of the resulting rotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly (or at least I don't know about a nice formula). But if you get the rotation matrix $R$, you can immediately calculate some Euler angles that will give you the same rotation matrix. Note that the answer might not be unique. Also note that you must specify which [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix) you want to use for your Euler angles. From the matrices provided in the link above, you can calculate the angles. For example, assuming that you have the $YXY$ convention, and indexing $R$ from $1$ to $3$, you get $\cos\beta=R_{22}$. If $\sin\beta\ne 0$, then you can use $$\alpha=\textrm{atan2}(R_{12},R_{32})\\\gamma=\textrm{atan2}(R_{21},-R_{23})$$
Note that if $\sin\beta=0$, then you have a degenerate case, a rotation purely around the $Y$ axis, with an angle say $\delta$, and you can have any $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ as long as $\alpha+\gamma=\delta$